# Projected Grid range matrix from DirectX to openGL?

Tags: android, opengl-es, grid, libgdx, directx

I try to implement a projected grid solution to display ocean. I'm following this article : http://habib.wikidot.com/projected-grid-ocean-shader-full-html-version

As it will be game for andoid I choose libgdx engine. The problem I met is how to calculate range (min/max) matrix mentioned in the paper. Currently I'm doing it like :

float[] frange=
        {
        x_max-x_min,    0,      0,  x_min ,
                  0,        y_max-y_min,    0,       y_min,
        0,      0,      1f, 0f ,
        0,      0,      0,  1f
        };

Matrix4 range=new Matrix4().set(frange);
range.tra(); // transpose

This matrix is multiplied with InverseViewprojection matrix of projector. The goal is teh projector to spread the projected grid in min max range calculated based on camera / plane intersection points.

The problem is that this matrix I take from the example implementation is using DirectX and do not work properly in my case. I try to switch Y/Z and receive better looking grid but still not 100% ok.

Can somebody help me with advice how to use the same matrix but for Open GL.

Comment: Just a quick quess: afaik DirectX uses row-major and OpenGL column-major matrices. Perhaps you need a transpose at some points in your code.

Comment: Yes, I do transpose (last line of my code here). If do not do it it doesn't work at all. I guess that the problem is that there is a diference in coordinatees range. GL use -1,1 DX use 0,1. Also I have feeling that in teh example from teh paper Z is up and I have Y up. So teh problem is how to convert the min max range. In the example it is done just x_max-x_min for scale and x_min for translation. Will it be the same if I use same logic but with diferent values in range (I suppose) for x_min and x_max

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. I just changed the order when multiply range matrix with projector matrix.